# how to use the SharedPreferrence value in another activity in android app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

in my app i am storing a value in Shared Preference and it gets stored successfully.
Following is a piece of my code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences( "idValue", 0 );
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString( "idValue", chap.getid() );
editor.commit();
Log.e("Shared Pref",""+chap.getid());
```

Now i want to use this value in some other activities with a condition whether it is null or has an value.

How to get this value in another activity.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("idValue", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
String idvalue = prefs.getString("idValue", "");
```

in any activity you need

Answer (score 1):

first define Your `public static SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences( "idValue", 0 );` as static in your main activity.

and other activity you can get value like this.

```
firstactivity_name.prefs.getString("idValue", null);
```