# how to save some value in sharedpreferences and get that in next activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm creating a Quiz App, I ask some questions and give options in the form of radio buttons, now I want to store value of of answer (plus on right answer and minus on wrong one) in `SharedPreferences` and show that result in other activity. I have searched and found this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234902/how-to-use-the-sharedpreferrence-value-in-another-activity-in-android-app)

I used that but still I'm unable to get my desired results 
My code Looks Like :

Main Activity which saves some value in `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private SharedPreferences saveScore;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
RadioGroup group;
RadioButton radioButton;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    saveScore = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);       
}
public void gotoNextAndSaveScore(View view) {
    if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != R.id.radio3){
        editor = saveScore.edit();
        editor.putInt("score", -1);
        editor.commit();
    }else{
        editor = saveScore.edit();
        editor.putInt("score", 1);
        editor.commit();
    }       
    Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

this is the Next Activity which tries to get values from `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity{

private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("score", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

    int value = preferences.getInt("score", 0);
    String score = "Your Score is : " + value;
    UIHelper.displayScore(this, R.id.tvScore, score );

}}
```

does any one know how to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the line

```
 saveScore = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To

```
saveScore =  getSharedPreferences("score",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
public class DataStorage {

private static String KEY;
public static SharedPreferences savedSession;

public void saveID(Context context, String msessionid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Editor editor = context
            .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("SESSION_UID", msessionid);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getID(Context context) {

    savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return savedSession.getString("SESSION_UID", "");
}
}
```

**Edit:**

```
 DataStorage mdata = new DataStorage();

public void gotoNextAndSaveScore(View view) {
if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != R.id.radio3){

   mdata.saveId(Mainactivity.this,1);
}else{
   mdata.saveId(Mainactivity.this,-1);
}
```

And then get value from `NextActivity`.

```
DataStorage mdata = new DataStorage();
mdata.getId(NextActivity.this);
```

Comment: Sorry, but may I ask you where to call the method of this class in my `MainActivity` class?

Answer (score 1):

Store the value when navigating to `nextActivity` during `onPause()` as below:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
      super.onPause(); 
      // Store values between instances here
      SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
      editor.putString("YourStringKeyValue", "StringValue"); // value to store
      // Commit to storage
      editor.commit();
    }
```

and get the data with that key in `next Activity`'s `onCreate` as below:

```
       SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", 0);
       String name= preferences.getString("YourStringKeyValue","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong preference file, the getPreference function on Activity returns a file private to that Activity.  You need to use the named file version- getSharedPreferences(name, mode)